# Laravel: htaccess is ignored on homestead?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have created an Laravel app which I locally develop with homestead and which in online on a production server.

I only have a SSL certificate for `www.mydomain.com` but not for `mydomain.com`,
thats why I force with `htaccess` a redirect to `https://www.*****`. I did this by changing the file `myproject/public/.htaccess` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/2311074

The redirect works fine on my production server but there is no redirect happening on my local environment with homestead. Why is the redirect ignored on my local environment?

Here is the full `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
    # [NC] is a case-insensitive match
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: I suppose your production server is not running Homestead?

Comment: @kerbholz yes thats right. My production server is not running Homestead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `SSH` into homestead and run command

```
flip
```

it will stop `nginx` and will start `apache`.

now your `.htaccess` will work.

PS

The other option is to use `type: apache` in `Homestead.yaml` file. 
But it is not working for me for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. My production server uses Apache and I need mod_rewrite. Laravel even comes with .htaccess files out of the box!

Here's an elegant solution I found on here.

1. Add the "type: apache" to my Homestead.yaml file.

   sites:

   map: mylocalapp.com

   to: /home/vagrant/code/public

   type: apache
2. Reprovision vagrant to use Apache.

   vagrant up --provision

[Solved from the answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691337/why-laravel-homestead-is-not-running-apache?rq=1)